# How does this sentence follow subject verb agreement?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context, subject-verb-agreement, grammar-myths

I dont understand how the following sentence is following correct subject and verb agreement.

- Do authors think that including examples from the **text files has** widespread applicability?

Grammarly thinks this sentence is correct. But I dont understand why? Should not it be the like following

- Do authors think that including examples from the **text files have** widespread applicability?

why "text files has" is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subject of "have" is not "the text files". The subject is the gerund "including". The gerund is singular, so "has" is the correct form for subject-verb agreement.

"The text files" is the object of the preposition "from", so it cannot be a subject.